# Delete the data which exist in one table and not exist in the other one?

Tags: sql, t-sql, informix

I want to select all rows which exist in specific table and not exist in the other table to delete them .

I write the following query but i get rows exist in both tables !!

```
SELECT  UNIQUE b.values_key FROM request_fo a INNER JOIN rm_trans  b 
ON b.values_key != a.req_year || ',' || a.req_ser
AND b.taskcode = 19
AND  b.values_key IS NOT NULL
AND a.req_year IS NOT NULL 
AND a.req_ser IS NOT NULL
```

---

I want to use the following to delete the data exist in `request_fo` and not exist in `rm_trans` :

```
DELETE request_fo 
FROM request_fo a
INNER JOIN
rm_trans  b 
ON b.values_key != a.req_year || ',' || a.req_ser
AND b.taskcode = 19
AND  b.values_key IS NOT NULL
AND a.req_year IS NOT NULL 
AND a.req_ser IS NOT NULL
```

Is this right ??

Comment: Different DBMS have different syntax for DELETE operations, especially DELETE with join operations.  You cannot automatically expect what works in MS SQL Server to work in Oracle, DB2, Informix, MySQL, PostgreSQL — it will usually but not necessarily work in Sybase.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:Then please what's the syntax to do `DELETE a 
FROM request_fo a
LEFT JOIN rm_trans  b  ON b.values_key = a.req_year + ',' + a.req_ser
                      AND b.taskcode = 19
WHERE  b.values_key IS  NULL;` in informix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to think in sets when you want to perform this sort of operation. You're using `!=` when you need `NOT IN (...)` or `NOT EXISTS (...)`.

Your clause `b.values_key != a.req_year || ',' || a.req_ser` is comparing every row from `a` with every row in `b`. In most cases, they won't equate. But there will be many examples where the `values_key` in this particular row matches `a.req_year || ',' || a.req_ser` in other rows of `a` than the one currently being compared. That's why you're getting data returned that does exist in both tables.

You want to try something like this:

```
DELETE FROM a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b
                    WHERE b.values_key = a.req_year || ',' || a.req_ser
                       AND b.task_code = 19)
```

You should also run that as `SELECT * FROM a WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)` to verify it first. I would.

Answer (score 5):

If you can not use the join syntax you can also use a subselect.

```
delete from t1
where t1 = something
and not exists
(
   select 1
   from t2
   where t1.key = t2.key
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the T-SQL syntax to do so:

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead, with `b.values_key IS  NULL` predicate in the `WHERE` clause, and use the alias `a` instead of the table name in the `DELETE` clause:

```
DELETE a 
FROM request_fo a
LEFT JOIN rm_trans  b  ON b.values_key = a.req_year + ',' + a.req_ser
                      AND b.taskcode = 19
WHERE  b.values_key IS  NULL;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d9e7/1).

Assuming that `req_ser` and `req_year` are of data type string, if they are integer cast them.

---

**How it works?**

`LEFT JOIN` will include those unmatched rows from the first table `request_fo` which is on the left of the `LEFT JOIN`, even if there is no entries satisfy the `JOIN` consition, and in this case the `values_key` value will be `NULL` for those unmatched rows.

For instance, see [**this demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e945d/6), the `2013 4` from the first table doesn't exist in the second table so its `values_key` will be `NULL`, so adding [`WHERE b.values_key IS NULL`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e945d/7) will give you those that is found in the fist table and not found in the second table.

Comment: why set `b.values_key IS  NULL` ?!